# ROS Hydro on ubuntu 13.10: installation problems

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone.
i've just installed last ubuntu's release on my computer (it seemed a good idea), then i tried to install even last release of ROS.
Sadly, that's what i get:

```
ubisum@biagioPC:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

do you know any breakthrough? thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93456/ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-13.10:-installation-problems/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Hydro is not available for Ubuntu 13.10 as apt-get package.
You can install from source, but possibly it is easier for you to install Ubuntu 13.04 instead.
Also see http://answers.ros.org/question/92526/ubuntu-1310/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0